# Can't execute cypher match queries in Neo4j JAVA

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to perform this query using ExecuteEngine:

```
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("match n-[:MOVE_TO]->(x) where n.name = \"-999622097\" return x");
```

But I get this error:

> expected START or CREATE

There are any way to perform a MATCH query in JAVA? without using START?

Tk!

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: start became optional in 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing the parens around `n`. Try this:

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[:MOVE_TO]->(x) WHERE n.name ="-999622097" RETURN x
```

Comment: that doesn't work. still reporting the same error. Sorry for the late response

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? START was required in versions prior to 2.0 I believe.

Comment: I also tried with this one:
start n=node(*) match (n)-[:MOVE_TO]->(x) where n.name = "-999622097" return x. In this case, the error was: "The property 'name' does not exist on Node[0]"
 NOTE: all of this queries works on the neo4j web server

Comment: Try using the execute method on GraphDatabaseService instead of ExecutionEngine. Do you get the same error?

Comment: I realized that I don't have that method on GraphDatabaseService